# Return a value based on matched value in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array consisting of (a) description, (b) the minimum number of years and (c) the maximum number of years:

```
$years_array = array( 
 array("Any", 0, 255),
 array("New", 0, 1),
 array("5 - 10yrs", 5, 10),
 array("10 - 20yrs", 10, 20)
);
```

Given both the minimum `$min` and maximum `$max` number of years, how do I match it to give the description `$description` in the array?

Example:

```
$min = 5, $max = 10 => $description = "5 - 10yrs";
```

Comment: Your question is pretty vague ... what do you mean? How can you get `"10 - 20yrs"`?

Comment: @MihaiIorga, yes, `"10 - 20yrs"` assuming that I have 10 as `$min` and 20 as `$max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick, dirty and just for showing a possibility...

```
<?php
$years_array = array( 
 array("Any", 0, 255),
 array("New", 0, 1),
 array("5 - 10yrs", 5, 10),
 array("10 - 20yrs", 10, 20)
);

function getYearDescription(&$years, $min, $max) {
 foreach($years as $year) {
  if($year[1] == $min && $year[2] == $max) {
    return $year[0];
  }
 }

 return "n/a";
}

echo(getYearDescription($years_array, 5, 10));
?>
```

I suppose you need an exact match

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function getDescription($min,$max) 
{
  // source
  $years_array = array( 
    array("Any", 0, 255),
    array("New", 0, 1),
    array("5 - 10yrs", 5, 10),
    array("10 - 20yrs", 10, 20)
  );
  foreach ($years_array as $yearRecord) {
    if ($min == $yearRecord[1] && $max == $yearRecord[2])) {
      return $yearRecord[0];
    }
  }
  return false;
}

getDescription(0, 255); // == "Any"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchArray($min, $max, $years_array)
{
  foreach($years_array as $years)
  {
    if($years[1] == $min && $years[2] == $max) return $years[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function match_desc($arr,$min,$max) { 
    // first filter an array to match $min and $max
    $filtered = array_filter($arr, function($v) use ($min,$max) { 
        list($desc,$miny,$maxy) = $v; 
        return $min == $miny && $max == $maxy; 
    });
    // return only descriptions
    return array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]; },$filtered);
}

match_desc(array( 
 array("Any", 0, 255),
 array("New", 0, 1),
 array("5 - 10yrs", 5, 10),
 array("10 - 20yrs", 10, 20)
), 0,1);
```

will return `array(0 => "New");`

This function considers you might have an array like

```
$years_array = array( 
 array("Desc1", 0, 255),
 array("Desc2", 0, 255),
);
```

so, feeding 0 and 255 as min and max will `return array(0 => "Desc1", 1 => "Desc2");`
if function doesn't match against passed min and max, it will return an empty array and it's easily can be checked with [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php).